# How to prevent react-spring from starting animation on each state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-spring

I have a DIV panel with different controls that should be animated to show and hide at a certain moment of time. At the same time, there are lots of elements inside which have different states.

The problem is when any element inside of the panel changes its state, the panel itself starting an animation (either show or hide animation). I think it's because the whole panel is re-rendered.

So, how should I explain to React Spring which state changes should force animation to restart? And how may I prevent parent panel DIV from re-render when children state are changed?

Comment: Could you share some code? Or a code sandbox?

Comment: Simple re-render will not start the animation again. I would like to see the code as well.